# How to check what is blocking my mDNS requests?

Tags: ubuntu, avahi

This is the situation. I have a home server that publishes multiple domains via avahi.

Avahi and resolvectl are installed on the client (ubuntu 22).

in the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` - `hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns`. Which seems normal.

But,

```
$ avahi-resolve -n whoami.homeserver.local
whoami.homeserver.local 192.168.0.4
```

But when trying to resolve the address via ping or curl

```
$ curl whoami.homeserver.local
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: whoami.homeserver.local
```

UPD:
Interesing - base name `homeserver.local` is correctly resolved via ping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to resolve a 3-label name over mDNS.

Normally, `mdns4_minimal` will resolve only 2-label names.

See [the source code of the libnss-mdns resolver libraries](https://github.com/avahi/nss-mdns/blob/master/src/util.h#L78):

```
// If mdns_allow_file is NULL, then this implements the "local" SOA
// check and two-label name checks similarly to the algorithm
// described at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201275. This means
// that if a unicast DNS server claims authority on "local", or if the
// user tries to resolve a >2-label name, we will not do mDNS resolution.
```

The mentioned Apple Support document no longer exists, but [can be viewed through archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20141108121109/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201275).

The `mdns_allow_file` mentioned here refers to build-time configurable `${sysconfdir}/mdns.allow` (usually `/etc/mdns.allow`). The `mdns4_minimal` tests for the existence of this file: if it exists, more extensive mDNS lookups are allowed. Without it, as is the default case, only two-label names of the form `<single_label>.local` are looked up over mDNS - and even that lookup will be skipped if a regular DNS SOA record for `local.` is found to exist.

When mDNS was introduced, it was soon found that many organizations had already set up internal DNS hierarchies as `.local` or `.organization.local`.

To minimize the hassle caused by the assignment of `.local` for mDNS use, a compromise was reached: by default, mDNS would only apply to two-label names ending in `.local` unless specifically enabled for wider use. This would allow names of three or more labels and ending in `.local` to be resolved exactly as before, but would reserve two-label names ending in `.local` for mDNS / Zeroconf / Bonjour purposes.

The file seems to be poorly documented, but the [commit message adding support for it is informative](https://github.com/avahi/nss-mdns/commit/eff6326436a65eef4fa195ea068575fbaf3e744d):

> Starting with version 0.5, `nss-mdns` has a simple configuration file `/etc/mdns.allow` for enabling name lookups via mDNS in other domains than `.local`. The file contains valid domain suffixes, seperated by newlines. Empty lines are ignored as are comments starting with #. To enable mDNS lookups of all names, regardless of the domain suffix add a line consisting of `*` only (similar to `nss-mdns` mode of operation of versions <= 0.4):
>
> ```
> # /etc/mdns.allow
> *
> ```
>
> If the configuration file is absent or unreadable `nss-mdns` behaves as if a configuration file with the following contents is read:
>
> ```
> # /etc/mdns.allow
> .local.
> .local
> ```
>
> i.e. only hostnames ending with `.local` are resolved via mDNS.
>
> If the configuration file is existent but empty, mDNS name lookups
> are disabled completely.

Reading the [source code of the function that decides if the name is allowed for mDNS lookup or not](https://github.com/avahi/nss-mdns/blob/master/src/util.c#L79) indicates that the two-label restriction applies only when the `/etc/mdns.allow` file does not exist (the `else` branch of the outermost  `if...then...else` clause). [Apparently the two-label heuristic was added 10 years after implementing the `mdns.allow` file.](https://github.com/avahi/nss-mdns/commit/8dd798485b119841f161d06076cb595a163f7fdd)

So, if you want your three-label mDNS name to work but to keep everything else functioning as-is, you would have to create an `/etc/mdns.allow` file with the following contents:

```
.local.
.local
```

Comment: Hmm, yep, thanks

I was sure that nss should allow mdns names anyway because, if I’m not mistaken, the standard says that any name before .local is not divided into domains and is treated as just a name string

Comment: That's yet another compromise between the original mDNS specification that proved to be a bit too idealistic and the reality of needing to minimize reactions like "we've had our `department.organization.local` internal DNS zones  for 20 years and now this newfangled mDNS blocks it? Well, then mDNS sucks, let's disable it everywhere!"